# Not able to compile C++ in NetBeans IDE - Gives error "CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application"

Tags: c++, netbeans, compiler-errors, mingw, netbeans-7

I'm trying to build a C++ application in NetBeans 7.3. I'm using the MinGW compiler & I set up the project as a new project from an existing makefile. When I try to compile, I'm getting the following error from NetBeans:

```
CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I've looked at the NetBean's forums and I've done the following:

1. Ensured that my `Path` variable included the MinGW bin.
2. Ensured that NetBeans C++ extensions were installed.

Can anyone give me some pointers on where to look next - I'm not terribly familiar with C++. I should mention that I'm running on a 64 bit machine, but I'm unsure if this is causing my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check these points too:

1. Make shure there are no blanks in paths (eg. path to gcc or source files should not contain any blanks)
2. Do you call any shellscript or other linux / unix stuff within your makefile?
3. If you setup a new project (like a default c/c++ application) - does this work?
4. Since you're using an existing source / makefile: can you compile your project on another system?
5. Do you have mingw *msys* installed?
6. are there any other informations or is this the only error / message you get?

What version of MinGw are you using?

Comment: Ollo, in order: 1 is taken care of, 2 - no, 3 - No, 4 Yes, 5, yes, 6, no. I even tried a super basic hello world, and I get the same message.

Comment: Thanks, thats realy strange. Some other checks: do you have any other compilers (eg. cygwin) on your system or does it work on earlier NB version (eg. 7.2 or 7.0)?

Comment: Can you compile a simple program through command line, without ide?